# Keep WebSocket connection alive after upgrade in Go

Tags: http, go, websocket

I am having issue in keeping websocket connection alive in go. In my code below, I assign 2 different ports to handle websocket (:8080) and for API request (:3300).

There is no issue when I am using websocket handler directly, but using API handler request and making new external request to the websocker handler, the connection closed directly. Any help is appreciated.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "time"

    "github.com/gobwas/ws"
    "github.com/gobwas/ws/wsutil"
)

func main() {
    go websocket()

    http.HandleFunc("/ws", func(rw http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
        if err != nil {
            http.Error(rw, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            return
        }

        url := fmt.Sprintf("http://127.0.0.1:8080?%s", r.URL.RawQuery)
        req, err := http.NewRequest(r.Method, url, bytes.NewReader(body))

        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            panic(err)
        }

        req.Header = make(http.Header)
        for h, val := range r.Header {
            req.Header[h] = val
        }

        httpClient := &http.Client{Timeout: time.Second * 10}
        httpClient.Do(req)

    })

    http.ListenAndServe(":3300", nil)
}

func websocket() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        conn, _, _, err := ws.UpgradeHTTP(r, w)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }

        go func() {
            defer conn.Close()

            for {
                msg, op, err := wsutil.ReadClientData(conn)

                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    return
                }
                err = wsutil.WriteServerMessage(conn, op, msg)
                if err != nil {
                    fmt.Println(err)
                    return
                }
            }
        }()
    }))
}
```

Comment: The :3030/ws handler connects to the :8080 endpoint using the HTTP protocol, not the WebSocket protocol.  The error returned from ws.Upgrade explains this.  Use a websocket client to connect to the server.  Why are you using two ports instead of one?

Comment: i want to do proxy connection to port 8080 for websocket connection. I thought i can upgrade to websocket using http handler, the doc also use http handler and upgrade to websocket. https://github.com/gobwas/ws#usage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in the question connects to the websocket endpoint using an HTTP request. Upgrade fails as a result.

Use the standard library [reverse proxy](https://godocs.io/net/http/httputil#ReverseProxy) to proxy the request.

A simpler approach is to is to call the websocket handler directly.  Move the handler to a top-level function:

```
func handleWS(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    conn, _, _, err := ws.UpgradeHTTP(r, w)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    go func() {
        defer conn.Close()

        for {
            msg, op, err := wsutil.ReadClientData(conn)

            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            err = wsutil.WriteServerMessage(conn, op, msg)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
        }
    }()
}
```

Use the handler in both servers.

```
func main() {
    go websocket()
    http.HandleFunc("/ws", handleWS)
    http.ListenAndServe(":3300", nil)
}

func websocket() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", http.HandlerFunc(handleWS))
}
```

Comment: handleWS function is a HTTP handler, isn't it? the RFC6455 implementation also use HTTP with websocket upgrade header request, so I thought I can create HTTP request with websocket upgrade in its header. Am I getting it wrong? because the doc also use HTTP handler, https://github.com/gobwas/ws#usage. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Thank you for helping, reverse proxy is the solution.